# Why can't I run virtualenv without root?

Tags: centos6.2, virtualenv

I'm trying to run virtual env and all the documentation says I don't need to run it as root (and probably shouldn't).  If I run it as root, everything works.  If I run it without root, I get:

```
[stats@crunch ~]$ virtualenv env
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.7.1.2
```

I believe I can change the ownership and it's the same difference, but I'd like to know why this is happening.  It's a fresh CentOS 6.2 installation.

Answer (score 1):

easy_install had installed virtualenv without read permissions for group or world (only execute).  Any idea why that happens?

Doing chmod -R 755 on the /usr/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv directory resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970597/342518), you probably need to look at environmental variables and write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error msg. You have to create "env" directory before executing virtualenv

```
mkdir env
virtualenv env
```

Comment: You should not have to pre-create the directory used by `virtualenv`.  The need to do so indicates that something is wrong with your installation.

Comment: I wish someone could come up with a perfect solution. At the moment, this works for me.